# Can you suggest any alternative for Statistics module?

Tags: nodes

We have a pretty descend traffic to our Drupal website, approximately 600 page views per minute. We have enabled the Drupal statistics module for storing the node page views.

At peek traffic hours, we observed a high usage of Disk I/O wait, and we doubt that it is due to statistics module. Please correct me if am wrong. If yes, kindly suggest some alternative method to implement node view counter.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Keep in mind that requests for modules are off-topic, for us.

Comment: Hi, Q+A needs questions that have a single, objective answer. It's not possible to provide such a thing when you're asking for a list of possible alternatives to a general, broad problem. The answers that have been provided demonstrate this perfectly, as each are unfocused and suggest a number of different approaches, without describing how to actually use any of them to solve your problem. Please take some time to write a more targeted question that fits into the rules in the [help]. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Here are some reports you get from it:

> - View pages that have recently been visited.
> - View pages that have been hit frequently.
> - View pages count per month, day of month, day of week, hour.
> - ...

Especially these reports should be what you're looking for (it includes hits for paths corresponding to a view):

- [Top pages](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/top_pages.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Title, Path and nr of Hits).
- [Recent hits](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/recent_hits.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Date of visit, Title, Path and User ID of the visitor).

Checkout the above (source) links to get an idea of which data are available.

The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also. This demo site also shows some additional blocks with reports also created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module module.

You may also want to look at the [visitors_schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.install?h=7.x-2.x#n37) to get an idea of the data that actually get logged (recorded) by this module.

In case it's not a perfect fit, it's probably a very good starting point for some custom reporting. Either via a custom module that would simply have to query the data maintained by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Or via a straight forward custom report created with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module,
and co-maintainer of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use

- [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module
- [Google Analytics Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module
- [Google Analytics Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter) module
- [jStats](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstats) module

> Statistics module saves data into the database and for a high traffic
>   site it can make a large number of writes to the database.

You may want to read this thread - https://groups.drupal.org/node/145294

Hope that helps